# Populating select elements in MaterializeCSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, materialize

I'm new to the Materialize CSS framework and I was wondering how I can populate the select component using JavaScript. I tried the following:

```
<select id='myselect'>
</select>
```

```
$('select').formSelect();
const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
x.map(item => {
    $('#myselect').append(`<option>${item}</option>`);
})
```

The select form component just appears empty. I also made sure to load my JavaScript files at the bottom of my HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

*Do by the inversed way...*

```
const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
x.map(item => {
    $('#myselect').append(`<option>${item}</option>`);
});

$('select').formSelect();
```

*The formPlugin add a cutom template and link an html list to the select option.*

*If you need to add item after the initialisation:*

- Add the items
- Destroy the formSelect
- Reinitialize it